# position the text in the required place

Tags: html, css, css-position

**HTML**

```
<div class="form">
    <!-- USERNAME BOX-->
    <label for="username"><b>Username or email address</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br>
    <!-- PASSWORD BOX -->
    <label for="password">
      Password
      <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value=""><br>
    <!-- SIGN IN BUTTON -->
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Sign in">

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form{
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
   padding: 15px;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
label{
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-align: left;
  }
input{
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 25px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
   text-indent: 5px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
   outline-color: dodgerblue;
  }
input[type="button"]{
   background: green;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 600;
   height: 30px;
   border: darkgreen;
  }
label a{
   float: right;
   transform: translateY(3px);
   text-decoration: none;
  }
```

I want **Forgot password?** to end exactly where the input field ended. I have tried to do this but i couldn't. Plese help me to fix this. It shifted towards right from the required position.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried to fix the issue.

Comment: Please go here to ask a good question and if you want an answer for your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following css for `label` so that label will be same width as `input`, and its `Forgot password?` aligns with input field.

```
   width: 300px;
   display: inline-block;
```

```css
.form{
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
   padding: 15px;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
label{
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-align: left;
   width: 300px;
   display: inline-block;
  }
input{
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 25px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
   text-indent: 5px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
   outline-color: dodgerblue;
  }
input[type="button"]{
   background: green;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 600;
   height: 30px;
   border: darkgreen;
  }
label a{
   float: right;
   /* transform: translateY(3px); */
   text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <!-- USERNAME BOX-->
  <label for="username"><b>Username or email address</b></label><br>
  <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br>
  <!-- PASSWORD BOX -->
  <label for="password">
    Password
    <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
  </label><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" value=""><br>
  <!-- SIGN IN BUTTON -->
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Sign in">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you positioned you forgot password on the wrong place.

```html
<div class="form">
    <!-- USERNAME BOX-->
    <label for="username"><b>Username or email address</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br>
    <!-- PASSWORD BOX -->
    <label for="password">
      Password
      
    </label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value=""><a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    <br> 
    <!-- SIGN IN BUTTON -->
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Sign in">

  </div>
```

Comment: I want it in the same line where the password lebel is in

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to remove the `<br>`s after the labels:

```
<div class="form">
  <!-- USERNAME BOX-->
  <label for="username"><b>Username or email address</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br>
  <!-- PASSWORD BOX -->
  <label for="password">
    Password
    <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
  </label>
  <input type="password" name="password" value=""><br>
  <!-- SIGN IN BUTTON -->
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Sign in">
</div>
```

Then, you need to add `display: block;` and `width: 310px;` to the label:

```
label {
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-align: left;
   display: block;
   width: 310px;
}
```